# Can't save products after setting related items (Invalid argument supplied for foreach())

Tags: product, product-attribute, products, save, related-products

I'm trying to set related products programatically, using the following code:

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$id="549";
$data=array($id=>array('position'=>1));
$product->setRelatedLinkData($data);
$product->save();
```

And I'm getting:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Bitnami\magento-1.9.2.2-1\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php on line 1180
```

Looking at the source code doesn't give any useful information. its from here:

```
$origData = $newObject->getOrigData();
/**
* get current data in db for this entity if original data is empty
*/
if (empty($origData)) {
   $origData = $this->_getOrigObject($newObject)->getOrigData();
}

/**
* drop attributes that are unknown in new data
* not needed after introduction of partial entity loading
*/
foreach ($origData as $k => $v) { // <-- HERE!!!
    if (!array_key_exists($k, $newData)) {
       unset($origData[$k]);
    }
}
```

I looked at dozens of examples online of how to update related products and my code should be fine. without the save() there's no exception but nothing is saved either.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

EDIT: I also tried to load the $product I'm changing like this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->load("754");
```

with hard-coded id, just to be sure.

Comment: Where are you running the code to set the related products?

Comment: @Smartie inside core_layout_block_create_after event, but only execute it on the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related block. I know it sound weird but its an experiment :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying that in the frontend and/or in a data/sql setup script you should:

- Set StoreId `$product->setStoreId(your_store_id);`
- Set The environment as admin.

> Set as Admin

```
if (!Mage::registry('isSecureArea')) {
    Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
}
Mage::app()->setUpdateMode(false);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

**NOTE** 
If you are doing that in the frontend (ie: product_view) you should go-back to the current (front) store after perform your changes.

Comment: I'm doing this inside core_layout_block_create_after  observer. so it means I need to set environment to be admin right? also, why do I need to set store id for the product if I'm using the current product from registery? thanks!

Comment: Set the `store_id` is always a good practice, but if you are using it there, probably you don't need to do it. I'm pretty sure that the error you have is related to environment, sincerely I'm not 100% sure if it's safe to change the store to admin there.

Comment: I thing that an ajax request to save such data would be more "prudent" and/or "safer". Block events are builded to add some view functionality I think that isn't the right place to perform the product save.